# Python: Extract fields from pdf forms into pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, pdfminer

I have a bunch of pdf forms with fillable text/date fields. I would like to build a script with a function that reads pdf fields and parses them into a dataframe. Does anyone with experience doing this know the best place to start?

Comment: check out tabula https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks. This looked promising, but I think it's having a hard time bc my form isn't so much tables as it is separate, fillable text and date fields. Running tabula returns a df with horribly mangled formatting.

Comment: There's also pyPDF2 https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/

Comment: Thanks! This has been helpful.